# MySQL mapping table insert constraint not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mapping table for customer and products. Here are the steps

```
    create table `customer_products` (
       `customer_id` bigint not null,
        `product_id` bigint not null,
        primary key (`customer_id`, `product_id`)
    );

     alter table `customer_products` 
       add constraint `FK7urin54lem7yxy6umxf899t16` 
       foreign key (`customer_id`) 
       references `customer` (`customer_id`);

    alter table `customer_products` 
       add constraint `FKtfgjfwfykaef4wjk00ofyqq8y` 
       foreign key (`product_id`) 
       references `product` (`product_id`);

   insert into customer_products values(7,5); //should get a contraint error
```

When I insert into this mapping table although the corresponsing entries are not there in the parent tables I am not getting an error in above `insert` statement . Do I need some extra option to put this constraint?

Comment: A constraint does not add rows to another table.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Can I restrict somehow to only add an entry if corresponding ids exist in parent tables?

Comment: . . That is what a foreign key constraint does.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Then why is my insert query getting successful. It should fail right. That is my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The JPA was using MyISAM engine to create tables and it doesn't support foreign key constraints. So once I modified the engine to InnoDB the problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This approch is not good.
But have a solution.

```
You can write a trigger on customer_products and set 'before insert'
```

You need to write more intaligent query to insert in parent tables that records not exist.